# In C# how do I have a process.WaitForExit(time) that overrides a standard process.WaitForExit()?

Tags: c#, process, waitforexit

I want it to wait for the process to end before continuing, but if it doesn't end in x amount of time, continue anyway. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You could probably have a separate thread created with a timer once you create and start the process that will end the process after x amount of time. An ultimate solution would be to have multiple threads for your processes unless other items rely on that object, then it gets tricky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There already is a a method [WaitForExit(int milliseconds)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which you can use.

That method will wait the given amount of ms and return then, if the process did not exit before.

If it returns true, the process had already exited, otherwise you might kill it on your own or continue your logic.

Comment: Thank you i didn't realize it was that simple